# Trying to initialise unknown number of variables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to initialize dictionaries, and I don't know that I'll need 3 or 4 or 10 or whatever.  So I tried the following:

```
dim wb1 as workbook
set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
dim strdict as new scripting.dictionary
  For c = 1 To 65536        'for all rows
    If strdict.Exists(wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4)) Then 
    'if that string has already been logged ie this is not the first pass of the current string, log it
      strdict(wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4)) = strdict(wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4)) + 1
    Else
      strdict.Add wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4), 1                
      'if that string is not present, add it to the dictionary
      dim left(wb1.Sheets(1).cells(1,4), 3) & "log" as Scripting.dictionary
    End If
  Next c
```

I can't say that I was *surprised* that

```
dim left(wb1.Sheets(1).cells(1,4), 3) & "log" as Scripting.dictionary
```

didn't work, but is there a way to accomplish what I'm thinking of?  Or is this something vba simply cannot do?

Comment: A dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: I considered that, but don't you still have to name them?  They can't share a name, but I don't know how to name them differently; the cell data was the obvious choice, but it doesn't seem to like using that.

Comment: You would need unique variable names anyways. Another approach is to use a single dictionaries with different keys for different cells e.g. join the cell address with a key to get a tagged key. On a separate note -- `For c = 1 To 65536` seems problematic. Do you really have 65 thousand rows of data?

Comment: You can totally use a dictionary of dictionaries - instead of a variable name the string you construct becomes the key to the "inner" dictionary.  `strdict.Add left(wb1.Sheets(1).cells(1,4), 3) & "log", New Scripting.Dictionary`

Comment: I don't have that much data, I just picked a big number so that the incoming data was guaranteed to be covered.  It only ever goes out to like 7 or 8 thousand (again, varying quantity of data), I could cut it down a bit.

Comment: Tim, do I not have to name the inner dictionary?  That's the thing I was iffy about.  So, if I wanted to refer to the inner dictionary, would it be `strdict(c(d))`, where c and d are numbers, for example?  And that would return the d'th entry of the c'th dictionary in strdict?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your eventual aim is here?  What do you need to do?  Inline code is done by surrounding your code with backticks

Comment: @GrahamPerry you should watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&t=242s&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=43).

Comment: Basically, there are a number of locations that come in, and each one of those locations has comments associated with it.  The comments associated with a location are not always the same as each other ie 1 location might have 5 or 6 different individual comments.  I just need to count them.  tl;dr: A has 1,1,2,1,3,2,4, I need it to look at A and say there were 3 ones, 2 twos, 1 three, 1 four.  But the number of unique letters and numbers is not guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: Let me get this straight, do you want multiple definitions for the same variable? Is that the problem? Myword1= Meaning1||Meaning2  Myword2=Meaning3 Myword3= Meaning2||Meaning3||Meaning5 ?

Comment: Sort of, yeah, only I thought that wasn't possible, so I was looking for a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing your need for multiple dictionaries based on the code you posted.
Seems like you just want to get distinct values and counts from Col D?

**EDIT:** updated based on your explanation

```
dim wb1 as workbook
dim dictCount as new scripting.dictionary
dim dictSub as new scripting.dictionary
dim k, kSub

set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

For c = 1 To 65536 

    k = wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(c, 4)

    'seen this key before?
    If Not dictCount.Exists(k) Then           
        dictCount.Add k, 0
        dictSub.Add k, New Scripting.Dictionary
    End If  

    dictCount(k) = dictCount(k) + 1 'increment count

    'track sub strings
    kSub = Left(k, 3)
    If dictSub(k).Exists(kSub) Then
        'increment the count
        dictSub(k)(kSub)=dictSub(k)(kSub)+1 
    Else
        dictSub(k).Add kSub, 0
    End If                 


Next c
```

Comment: Mentioned it above, but it might be easier in a cleaner thread: each string that's being recorded has sub-strings attached to it that need to be recorded and counted.  I don't think I can do that in one dictionary; one dictionary to count the strings, and one dictionary to track the substrings is (I think) necessary.

Comment: A single key can't have different substrings (because they'd be different keys).

Comment: That's what I figured.  What you posted after the edit was...well, a lot more elegant than what I had,.  I was wondering, while I was trying to understand it - I've not see the `dictSub(k)(ksub)` before.  Is that just referring to the sub-dictionary inside of dictSub?  So, dictSub has a dictionary keyed to k, and that in turn has a keyed entry called ksub?  I'm reading that correctly?

Comment: Yes - that's how it works: you can nest as deep as you want but at some point it gets... complicated.

Comment: Okay, so that was pretty good.  There was like, one or two things to change, but mostly just because the substrings were kept in column 5 instead of 4, etc, you know, minor stuff.  Thanks!